# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader[] org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.getClassLoaders()'

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

While running my selenium code as testng, I'm getting the above error.
Below is my pom.xml file.

Here is the complete console log
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.9.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader[] org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.getClassLoaders()'
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector.getProviders(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:252)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector.access$000(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:53)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector$ForCopyOnWriteThreadContextMap.(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:192)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createDefaultInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.ContextMapLookup.(ContextMapLookup.java:34)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.(Interpolator.java:126)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.(AbstractConfiguration.java:129)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.(NullConfiguration.java:32)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.(LoggerContext.java:86)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:233)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:206)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:131)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:118)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:148)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:30)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.lambda$getLogger$0(Logger.java:30)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:30)
at org.testng.TestNG.(TestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNGFactory7_8.createRemoteTestNG(RemoteTestNGFactory7_8.java:16)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:67)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>FreeCRMTestAutomation</groupId>
  <artifactId>FreeCRMTest2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>FreeCRMTest2</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.9.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.guicedee.services/sl4j -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.guicedee.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>sl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13.5</version>
    </dependency>
    

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Strong recommendation upgrade all plugins to most recent versions https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ The scope for testng seemed to be wrong, because it's a test dependency etc.

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise update all the plugins and changed scope for testng from 'compile' to 'test' but didn't work. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The error occurred because my downloaded testng and maven dependency testng version have mismatched. So I updated my downloaded testng from eclipse marketplace and it worked.